# How to optimize mysql query registration

Tags: php, mysql

At the time of registration, I am checking for there field `username`, `email`, `phonenumber`

With three query. snippet is following:

```
$query = "SELECT *
              FROM 
                users 
              WHERE  username='$userName'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->con);
    $count_username = mysql_num_rows($result);
  if($count_username <= 0){
  $query = "";$result = "";
    $query = "SELECT *
              FROM 
                users 
              WHERE email='$email' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->con);
    $count_email = mysql_num_rows($result);
  }
  if($count_username <= 0 && $count_email <= 0){
  $query = "";$result = "";
    $query = "SELECT *
              FROM 
                users 
              WHERE  phone_number='$phone'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->con);
    $count_phone = mysql_num_rows($result);
  }
```

Is there is way to do this with single query, or is there is other way to optimize this code??? 
Sorry for using mysql extension.

If i use single query:

```
$query = "SELECT *  FROM  users WHERE  username='$userName' && email='$email' && phone_number='$phone'";
```

I am unable to show different error:

- username exists
- email exists
- phone exists

I don't want to show error like:

```
username/phone/exists exists
```

Comment: do you want to know if atleast of the value exist on the table?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use 3 fields to make a user unique? Most sites use either username or email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have something like this:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN username = '$userName' THEN 'username exists'
            WHEN email = '$email' THEN 'email exists'
            ELSE 'phone exists'
        END Result
FROM    users
WHERE   username = '$userName'
        OR email = '$email'
        OR phone_number = '$phone'
```

Comment: Query is good but by default its giving `phone exists`. We should add condition for phone also. Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22236/6

Comment: @Manwal why do you need to have a default value when the returned records are based on the filters.  there is a typo error `s` in the case statement. it should be `deepak` rather than `deepaks`.

Comment: @jhon when i was checking for if no field match so i have placed `deepaks` and all not matching values for all field. Than its returning `phone exists` with your query if i uses `ELSE 'phone exists'`

Comment: @Manwal so out of curiosity, why is the value in `where` clause different from the `case` statement in the `select` clause? of course it will return `phone exist` because it is assumed that the record is filtered by the `phone_number`.

Comment: @jhon Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22236/3. Its giving phone exists while phone is not in table. How to fix it????

Comment: i have added some explanations here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da730/1 if it still doesn't satisfies you, i don't have anything more to say.